# How to give focus to NSWindow loaded from NIB?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I'm using `NSWindowController` to load a window from a NIB. However, when I call `showWindow:`, the window is visually topmost, but the focus remains where it was (instead of moving it to the new window).

It's easy to see this happening when the first window (with keyboard focus) is moved slightly, before creating the new window (via cmd+n). This is the result:
[image]
The bottom, focused window is the original window. The unfocused window on top is the newly created window.

This is the relevant code:

AppDelegate.h:

```
- (IBAction)newDocument:(id) sender;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (IBAction)newDocument:(id) sender {
    [[[FooController alloc] init] showWindow:self];
}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self newDocument:self];
}
```

FooController.h:

```
@interface FooController : NSWindowController { }
@end
```

FooController.m:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"FooWindow"];
    return self;
}
```

FooWindow.xib:
A freshly created Window xib, without modifications.

MainMenu.xib:
The default MainMenu.xib, with its window deleted.

Calling `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` on the window in the controller's `windowDidLoad` method does not appear to focus the new window. Setting the File's owner of FooWindow.xib to `FooController` also did not appear to help.

What is the correct way to load and show a window from a NIB so that it does receive keyboard focus?

**Edit:** It looks like `NSWindowController`'s `window` method returns `nil`, which explains why calling methods on `window` doesn't do anything. But why is it `nil`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I found the cause of this problem.

The xib's File's owner must be set to the controller, and (this is the part I didn't know about) you have to connect the controller's `window` outlet to the window itself.

Having done that, it just works. No `makeKeyWindow`, `makeMainWindow` or `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` needed.

Comment: Obviously a very old answer, but without an actual screenshot of what this looks like after it's configured correctly, this isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps makeMainWindow: or makeKeyWindow: helps

Comment: Calling these from `windowDidLoad` does not focus the new window. Should they be called from elsewhere, perhaps?

Comment: I think they should be called after the makeKeyAndOrderFront: call

Comment: That's what I tried before. Whatever combination and order of `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, `makeMainWindow` and `makeKeyWindow` I put in `windowDidLoad`, the new window does not obtain focus.